# How to build Dockerfile on Windows via HTTP API?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop, docker-build, httpapi

I installed the docker on the Windows machine. Then I exposed the docker daemon to the localhost for the docker HTTP API usage.

Then I wrote simple Dockerfile and try to build it in the following way:

```
curl http://localhost:2375/build?dockerfile=/build?dockerfile=file:///D:/AAA/Dockerfile&t=ooouuu
```

But in the response I received followed error:

```
{"message":"page not found"}
"t" is not internal or external command, executable command or package file
```

If I understand correctly I used parameters in wrong way. Is it true?
How it could be fixed?

Comment: You need to make sure to quote your command-line arguments: your local shell is splitting the command on the `&`.  You also need to include the build context as a tar file in the POST body (you can't pass a `file:` URL in the query string like that).  Also **turn off HTTP access to the daemon**: it is incredibly dangerous.  A [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) might be easier to use than manual `curl` commands.

Comment: @David Maze, Hi! Thank you for the answer! Yes, I know that Docker SDK is much better but I need use HTTP API in privat network (it is company policy). You said that build context should be as tar file. Could you please give a some sample of query string? Also I don`t understand what is the context? Is it Dockerfile? So I just need to compress Dockerfile?

Comment: To be absolutely clear: anyone who can reach the Docker socket can **trivially root the host**.  I'd recommend using a dedicated continuous-integration system to build images, or else use local `docker` CLI commands over an ssh connection.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thx, I solve all troubles) The look from my side: I work on some kind of automation, I am write some kind of continuous-integration system. In my case any local docker CLI commands completely unusable, because they are needs a lot of work with parsing and error handling. So I have only one usable way - that is HTTP access